# Disabling shopping basket in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm currently creating a shop, and using WooCommerce. The shop doesn't need the shopping basket element. Users should only be able to buy one product at a time, instead of adding stuff to the basket they go straight to the payment process. Wondering what the best way to do this is? I have come across snippets that let you turn the add to cart button link go straight to the checkout:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

but this isn't foolproof in disabling the shopping cart. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: You're better off asking at http://community.woocommerce.com

Answer (score 2):

The shopping cart is a main structure of the WooCommerce checkout process and cannot be completely disabled.

As there is no exact solution, the best way to do what you want, in my opinion, is go to WooCommerce Settings -> Checkout and remove the selected page for the cart. This way, there will be no front-end for the cart whatsoever, although selected products will be saved in the cart structure (the system needs to know what to charge during the checkout).

Combine this with your redirection function, edit the templates for the cart-related messages (so that the go to cart buttons take you to the checkout page) or remove them completely) and you're as close to disabling the cart as humanly possible.